# X11 forwarding request failed to my OS X machine

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding, xquartz

I do not understand what is keeping me from making an X11 tunnel to my Mac at home, which is running OS X 10.10.2.  I'm getting this (hostnames redacted for privacy):

```
cook47@rcmac (~ ): ssh -Y mymac
X11 forwarding request failed
Last login: Thu Apr  9 11:12:13 2015 from xxx.xxx.xxx
```

In my sshd_config I have set X11Forwarding yes, and 
I tried to crank up the debugging with LogLevel DEBUG3 but I don't see much in the system log.  Also, I tried restarting X11.app but no changes. 
Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, never mind, I found it.  I was using a trick (ControlMaster) in my ssh config file to share ssh connections, so my new connections were reusing an old connection.